# No newlines in php echo from mysql

Tags: php, html

I have a news section on my website that has inline edit via ajax. I write some text, it gets stored and it get's displayed.

But for some reason there are no newlines or line breaks as they call them. I tried numerous stuff. And the only way a newline is displayed is if i press 'Enter' manually. Otherwise neither wordwrap nor nl2br help.

```
echo ' <span class="subheader">  <strong>'.$array["title"].
     '</strong>  </span>  <br />  '.
     '<div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px; width="20px"">'.
     '  <div id="quickDeleteNewsItem">  '.
     '<div style="width:20px;" id="post_message_'.
     $array['id'].'" style="display: inline;">'.
     $array["content"].'</div>  </div>  </div>  ';
```

Comment: If you don't press Enter key, why do you expect any line breaks?

Comment: Erm, most websites dont need for a person to press enter, they just get added, for me however that is not the case

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer this, we'll need to see some code.

What code are you `echo`ing when you expect a line break?

With the information posted now, all I can say is: If you aren't seeing line breaks when viewing text in a `<div>`/`<p>`, you need to either use line breaks (`<br />`) or put each paragraph of text in your news section in a block-level element, like a `<p>` tag.

Comment: I am sorry. Seems i can't post the code, since this site does not allow line breaks as well. I press enter and then it suddenly posts the comment. If you can read this then:          echo'
          <span class="subheader">
            <strong>'.$array["title"].'</strong>
         </span>
         <br />
      <div style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px; width="20px"">
      <div id="quickDeleteNewsItem">
      <div style="width:20px;" id="post_message_'.$array['id'].'" style="display: inline;">'.$array["content"].'</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      ';

Comment: First of all, you need to change `width=20px` to `width:20px`. Next, it seems as though the HTML is being `echo`ed directly into a `<div>`, so you should look into using PHP's nl2br (new line to break tag). Look here: http://php.net/nl2br

Comment: I already tried nl2br and wrote in the first comment, that it does not work. And i've added width=20px because the div gets stretched with the text.

Comment: Look at what I suggested you change it to. The equals sign needs to be changed to a colon.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what is the final result of the `echo`? Does it contain `<br />` elements? Perhaps your initial news text doesn't actually contain any line breaks at all, so the bug might lie elsewhere.

Comment: I changed it, but still the text has no linebreaks and just stretches(without the div, thanks to width 20px)

Comment: No, the code contains no <br /> elements at all with nl2br unless when typing the text i press 'Enter' to add the newlines myself

Comment: @user529018 - Holding `shift` and pressing enter allows newlines in comment boxes, just like Pidgin for those in the know ;-)

Comment: If the code contains no line break elements, then the nl2br function isn't being fed any line breaks. Your bug probably exists earlier in the process.

Comment: I have no idea where though. I have coded the website myself and this bug is the only one that is troubling me.

Comment: I don't know what to say, other than the line breaks from the "uploaded" news text aren't ending up being passed to the nl2br function. Somewhere, the line breaks are being stripped, or they never actually existed in the first place.

Comment: Well, when i view the html source from the browser, there is no <br /> or visible line break.

The only thing that comes to mind is ajax's code

POSTRequest('action=edit_news&text='+encodeURIComponent(cbobject)+'&newsid='+cID,'xmlhttp.php');

Answer (score 0):

try to encode content with encodeURIcomponent when posting it via ajax.

```
content = encodeURIComponent(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to see more of your code. I can think of at least three places the data is held:

- In a  on your page for editing
- In the  on your page for viewing
- In the database

and two types of line break:

- Hard breaks from when you have pressed enter (applies to all three data stores)
- Soft breaks, where the line is longer than they box containing it (applies to textarea and div, maybe between different words).

It sounds to me that you are seeing soft breaks in your textarea, but not when the text is moved to the div using javascript (or using php and a database?). If so, then it's almost certainly that the containing div is too wide - use firebug (or similar) to inspect the div and make sure it is being set at the correct width.

Answer (score -1):

replace the line brakes with html brakes

```
str_replace("\n","<br />\n",$data)
```

Comment: PHP has a function for it: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) - and he mentioned it doesn't work for him.